# how to prevent dynamic span formation in JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a registration form, validation is done by JavaScript. If validation fails it will shows error in span attribute in dynamically bellow eachy field. But problem is that if the validation is true, the span is generated but not visible. So there is additional blank space after onchange. How can I solve this?

```
form.validate({
    doNotHideMessage: false, //this option enables to show the error/success messages on tab switch.
    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
    errorClass: 'validate-inline', // default input error message class
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input

    rules: {
        birth_town: { 
            parentname: true,  
            required: true
        },
        birth_district: {  
            parentname: true, 
            required: true
        },
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "select one ",
            minlength: jQuery.format("select one")
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: add a css class to this span and set `display:none` in it.

Comment: If you create error-holding span dynamically make sure you don't do this before validation happens but only if validation fails.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov even if he does that, consider following case. User enters incorrect value and he creates and append a error span. Now user corrects it so he hides it, but still space take by span will be there. This is a common issue if you use `visibility:hidden` to hide an element.

Comment: @Rajesh  Why space do you think the space will be still taken if you hide span? Check fork of your fiddle - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/tajm2ok8/1/)

Comment: @Nilolay, even you have set display as none.

Comment: @Rajesh, did he say he is using `visibility:hidden` ?

Comment: The behavior he described happens with `visibility: hidden `

Comment: @Rajesh, what if he is adding span with `display:block` and some padding before validation starts so it remains empty but stays in place even if validation is ok ?

Comment: My friend padding appears inside element so hiding it will hide padding as well. Also let's not fight over it. Let the OP decide which approach suits him.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/tajm2ok8/)

#### Code

```js
function hide() {
  var err = document.getElementById("err1");
  err.className = "hidden";
}

function invisible() {
  var err = document.getElementById("err1");
  err.className = "invisible";
}

(function() {
  var val = document.getElementById("txt1").textContent;
  if (val.length == 0) {
    var err = document.getElementById("err1");
    err.innerHTML = "Enter some text";
    err.className = "invisible";
  }
})()
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.invisible {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<br/> <span class="error" id="err1"></span>

<input type="text" id="txt2">
<br/> <span class="error" id="err2"></span>

<button onclick="hide()">hidden</button>
<button onclick="invisible()">invisible</button>
```

Comment: i have about 50 fields , am i apply this to all?

Comment: The thing is, when you hide element using visibility, element is rendered but not shown so it captures it's space.

Comment: so here you validated for two fields, can you help me to avoid formation of  that span if validation fails

Comment: You can create these spans anytime. Just add a generic error class which has property `display:none` and add `display:block` in *validate-inline*

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in CSS.

You probably set somewhere top or bottom (or both) margins for your `validate-inline` class. The Validate plugin attaches this class to both incorrectly filled input and following error span.

You can see it in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/t4q068z7/). 
Try to click 'Submit' with inputs empty. You will see error messages popping up. Then try to fill the first input. Error for that one hides but space remains. This is because the second input keeps class `validate-inline` and it is its margin that keeps the space not the hidden error span of the first input.

Try to remove margins from `validate-inline` class in your CSS and see if that helps.

PS. Also I'm not sure about `parentname: true` - didn't find this in plugin rules documentation and jsFiddle won't work with it so I removed them from rules.